# How to Bind Data From Db to Combobox in Kendo UI with MCV 4

Tags: c#, razor, kendo-combobox

I want to bind data in  my DB to this combobox but it always failed to bind. There's nothing inside the combobox when i try to run it. Please help me. Thanks. 
Controller:

```
[Authorize]
        public JsonResult GetProvinsiByJSON()
        {
            var propinsi = db.Tbl_Propinsi.Where(b => b.flag == "Y").Select(b => new { Value = b.id_propinsi, Text = b.propinsi });
            return Json(propinsi, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

View:

```
<div>
            <form> 
                <div class="form-group"> 
                    <label for="kategori">Tambah Kota</label>
                    <br/>
                    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                      .Name("propinsi")
                      .Placeholder("Pilih Provinsi")
                      .DataTextField("Text")
                      .DataValueField("Value")
                      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:40%;" })
                      .Filter("contains")
                            .DataSource(source => { source.Read(read => read.Action("GetProvinsiByJSON", "Lokasi")); })
                    )
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kota" name="kota" placeholder="Nama Kota">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Simpan</button> 
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Is your controller returning data?

2.) Maybe try removing this line:

```
.Filter("contains")
```